# Disabling NVIDIA card on hybrid graphics laptop

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I have MSI GP60 2QE laptop with Intel HD 4600 and NVIDIA 940M graphics. I dual booted Windows 10 with Ubuntu 15.10 and noticed, that on Ubuntu NVIDIA card is always on what makes my battery last about 2h. Can I disable that card and force system to run on Intel integrated graphics? I use Ubuntu only for coding so I don't need advanced graphics enabled. Also, I can't disable card in BIOS since I'm using it on Windows.

Comment: Bumblebee might be a good solution? It will use the integrated graphics by default, but you can still run heavier applications with your NVIDIA card if necessary. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Currently I have my NVIDIA card fully Disabler, but I think I'll give it a shot. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings**.
- Go to **PRIME Profiles**.
- Select **Intel**.
- Log out and back in or reboot.

Now you are using Intel graphics.

[image]

---

**Update addressing your comments that you cannot access NVIDIA X Server Settings:**

To open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (it's the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key) and type "NVIDIA".

If it doesn't appear, maybe the installation of the NVIDIA drivers is not complete.
In that case, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
```

Then look for it again and you will find it.

Comment: I can't find X Server Settings, do I have to set anything to see them?

Comment: I know, but no results are found...