# How can I force the X server to use my nvidia card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have 2 external monitors connected to the docking station. I can only make 1 of them to work.

I am pretty sure that to drive the second monitor I will need to use the NVidia adapter.

It used to work while I was on the proprietary nvidia drivers. Had to switch no nouveau (Xephyr wouldn't support OpenGL with the proprietary drivers).

I can see in Xorg.0.log:

```
[     4.367] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1028:05cc rev 6, Mem @ 0xf5400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[     4.367] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0ff6:1028:15cc rev 161, Mem @ 0xf4000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
```

Xorg sees the nvidia adapter (PC: 1:0:0) but does not load the nouveau driver. How can I force it to do so?

Note: going back to the proprietary driver is not an option.

Hardware: Laptop Dell M4800 with a docking station

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

dmesg: http://pastebin.com/9J0pq6tn

Xorg.0.log: http://pastebin.com/NWj5tsS6

xrandr command to align the 2 working monitors:

```
xrandr \
  --output HDMI1 --off \
  --output VIRTUAL1 --off \
  --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate left 
  --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x760 --rotate normal --dpi 150/eDP1\
  --output VGA1 --off
```

(eDP1 is the build-in monitor, DP1 is the external monitor)

xrandr command that used to work with the proprietary drivers:

```
xrandr \
  --output VIRTUAL1 --off \
  --output DP1 --off \
  --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x840 --rotate normal \
  --output HDMI1 --off \
  --output VGA1 --off \
  --output DP-5 --off \
  --output DP-4 --off \
  --output DP-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate left \
  --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3000x552 --rotate normal \
  --output DP-1 --off \
  --output DP-0 --off
```

Port DP-3 from the proprietary driver is now named DP1 (probably by the Intel driver?

Port DP-2 from the proprietary driver is the one I would like to use

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3000 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+760 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.04*+  40.03    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected 1080x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

HDMI1 and VGA1 are unusable (blocked by the docking station)

Tried to get rid of the docking station but had the same problem - the Intel driver alone would not drive 3 video outputs.

OS is Lubuntu 16.04 (upgraded from 15.10)

Comment: Having `nvidia-prime nvidia-settings` packages [change it from NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/741677/349837)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit. Had these 2 files:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-352_hybrid.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-346_hybrid.conf
```

Both of them had `blacklist nouveau` and `alias nouveau off` which was preventing the nouveau driver from loading.

With these 2 removed I was able to see all outputs and configure all 3 monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this will fix your issue, but you should [check out this ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) regarding hybrid graphics and how to use switcheroo to activate the different cards.

It solved my issue when trying to use my hybrid ati Sony laptop that kept losing the Intel drivers and not the ati.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link to HybridGraphics docs. Unfortunately it did not help, directory `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo` does not show up on my system even after an edit of the grub options and a reboot. It does have an advice on NVidia Optimus - mostly saying it would not work :-(.

Comment: Awe that stinks!  I was so hoping that would be the fix for you. Oh well, maybe someone else will have a better idea.