# playonlinux not using nvidia

Tags: playonlinux

I have 2 graphics in my laptop: Intel and Nvidia.
I have installed Nvidia drivers like this:

```sh
sudo apt install nvidia-340 # Nowadays nvidia-driver-nnn
```

I have [selected Nvidia in PRIME profile in Nvidia-x-server](https://askubuntu.com/q/741677/349837).
My Steam games are now using Nvidia card.
But when I run games in playonlinux, they are still using Intel because they are running slow. How to force playonlinux games to use Nvidia?

Comment: I have installed  primusrun and append it in desktop launcher ..but i get "error in PQL wine" when I run it

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnLinux may require that you install Windows components before it can use your graphics acceleration -- d3dx9, for instance, or DirectDraw.  Which of these you might need is dependent on the Windows program you're running, and what Wine version you're running it under.

Advice on this is likely best sought from someone who knows both your program and PlayOnLinux or Wine.  Sometimes you can find tutorial pages (I've seen them for games like Path of Exile and There, as well as chat systems like IMVU), sometimes you can find an actual person who can help with specific issues -- and sometimes you can't.